# Can I use variables in The Foreman as a Puppet ENC?

Tags: puppet, foreman

Is it possible to set variables like server_role=webserver, allow_root=false in The Foreman as a Puppet ENC?

And does the Foreman as an ENC support hierarchies? E.g. make a group of webservers, that all have a specific module?

Or is the only thing you can do add modules to individual nodes?

Comment: 6 questions in 30 minutes? what's going on?

Comment: @Chopper3 A thirst for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

In Foreman:

1)
Smart variables are a tool to provide data (Key / Value), normally to your puppet ENC, depending on a set of rules. They are intended to be a stepping stone to full parameterized classes.

Smart variable is usually associated with a puppet class, and may have multiple values, all depending on hierarchical context or various conditions a user can wish to apply.

[source](http://theforeman.org/manuals/1.1/index.html#4.2.4SmartVariables)

2)There are hostgroups.